# ansible dictionary key value pairs

Tags: json, ansible

I am new to Ansible/json and I am trying to parse the following json:

```
{
    "resultCPU": {
        "changed": false,
        "msg": "All items completed",
        "results": [
            {
                "ansible_facts": {
                    "CPU": "6",
                    "VM": "tigger"
                },
            {
                "ansible_facts": {
                    "CPU": "4",
                    "VM": "pooh"
            },
```

I need to set the value of the items in this json so that pooh=4 and tigger=6.  I will need to refer to both these values later (advice on how to do that would help as well).

I have tried using `cpuvm "{{ resultCPU.results |selectattr('VM') |map(attribute='CPU')|list }}"` but it complains "'dict object' has no attribute VM".

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `selectattr` ignored the `ansible_facts` between `results: []` and the `VM` you tried to `map`. Thankfully, the `attribute` kwarg understands dot notation

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: >-
      VMs are {{ resultCPU.results | map(attribute="ansible_facts.VM") | list }}
      CPUs are {{ resultCPU.results | map(attribute="ansible_facts.CPU") | list }}
```

The [`together` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/collections/ansible/builtin/together_lookup.html) may interest you, too

and as for "I will need to refer to both these values later (advice on how to do that would help as well)." that is usually what [`set_fact:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/collections/ansible/builtin/set_fact_module.html) is used for, but without more specifics about what you have tried and what shape you are expecting, it's hard to give a more specific answer